# Why does macOS create file mounts for each app?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, finder, mount

I installed a lot of apps on my new MacBook, and I can see my desktop is filling with file mounts for each app. The Finder is also listing them like this.

[image]

Can someone please help me understand why that happens? What is the use of those mounts? Is there a way I can control/hide/stop that?

Comment: The idea of these mounts is analogous to previously having to insert a floppy or CD into your computer to install new software. It's up to you to then unmount - eject - them after you've finished.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These seem to be installers DMGs. You can unmount and discard them after installing the apps in your computer, typically by copying them to /Applications or ~/Applications.

Comment: Some of those contain an installer app which needs tro be run by double clicking not just copying.

Comment: Thanks. I removed all. But every time I open Chrome, it creates a new one. Any idea why?

Comment: I think the reason is that you have open tabs that correspond to download URLs *and* you have "Always Open Files Of This Type" enabled for .dmgs, so every time Chrome is opened it'll download them. To stop this from happening, check that you don't have open tabs with .dmg URLs in them.

Comment: I just checked. No tabs as such :-/

Comment: What do you mean it creates a new one?  Did you properly copy Chrome to the Applications folder?  It might be running from the DMG which would put it back.

Comment: Thanks, I've been using the wrong icon (i.e. the DMG one) to start it. changed it and the problem solved. Thanks guys.